# How to get URL in jQuery

Tags: jquery, url, filepath

I am currently using this code:

`jQuery("input[type=file]").filestyle({ 
        image: "http://localhost:8888/davidgray/wp-content/themes/davidgray/images/browse.png",
        imageheight : 22,
        imagewidth : 72,
        width : 460
    });`

However when I switch it over to live I of course want the URL that it's going to be on, how do I make this dynamic?

Cheers,
Steve

Comment: Use a relative URL? (Or are you not asking about the `localhost` part?)

Comment: `window.location` and it's brethren didn't get kidnapped by jQuery. You don't have to overthink it.

Answer (score 3):

Just use a relative URL

```
    jQuery("input[type=file]").filestyle({
        image: "/davidgray/wp-content/themes/davidgray/images/browse.png",
        imageheight : 22,
        imagewidth : 72,
        width : 460
    });
```

Comment: Hi, on localhost it will be;

/davidgray/wp-content/themes/davidgray/images/browse.png

However on live it will be:

/wp-content/themes/davidgray/images/browse.png so that isn't going to work...

Comment: So the only difference being it has "davidgray" at the front of the URL?

Comment: Dev is http://localhost:8888/davidgray/wp-content etc and live is going to be http://davidgray.co.uk/wp-content.

Answer (score 0):

Use window.location ?

here is an article worth reading.

http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-window-location

(This is assuming you do not know the relative url)